# Program keeps breaking

Tags: c++

Write the definition of the function moveNthFront that takes as a parameter a positive integer, n. The function moves the nth element of the queue to the front. The order of the remaining elements remains unchanged. For example, suppose:

queue = {5, 11, 34, 67, 43, 55} and n = 3.

After a call to the function moveNthFront:

queue = {34, 5, 11, 67, 43, 55}.

Add this function to the class queueType. Also, write a program to test your method.

Here is my header

```
#ifndef queueType_H
#define queueType_H
#include<iostream>

class queueType
{
private:
    class Queue
    {
        friend class queueType;
        int value;
        Queue *next;
        Queue(int value1, Queue *next1 = NULL)
        {
            value = value1;
            next = next1;
        }
    };
    // These track the front and rear of the queue
    Queue *front;
    Queue *rear;
    Queue *head;


public:
   void moveNthFront(int);
```

Here is the cpp for the header.

```
#include"queueType.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

queueType::queueType() {
front = NULL;
rear = NULL;
}

queueType::~queueType() {
clear();
}

void queueType::enqueue(int num)
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        front = new Queue(num);
        rear = front;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = new Queue(num);
        rear = rear->next;
    }
}
void queueType::dequeue(int &num)
{
    Queue *temp;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "The queue is empty.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        num = front->value;
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

bool queueType::isEmpty() const
{
    if (front == NULL)

        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int queueType::search(int x)
{
    if (front == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        Queue *aptr = front;
        while (aptr != NULL)
        {
        if (aptr->value == x)
            return count;
            aptr = aptr->next;
            count++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

void queueType::clear()
{
    int value;   // Dummy variable for dequeue

    while (!isEmpty())
        dequeue(value);
}
void queueType::remove(int pos)
{
    if (front == NULL)
        return;
    else if (pos == 0)
        front = front->next;
    else
    {
        int count = 0;
        Queue *now = front, *past;
        while (now != NULL && count != pos)
        {
            past = now;
            now = now->next;
            count++;
        }
    if (now)
        {
            past->next = now->next;
            delete now;
        }
    }
}
void queueType::insert(int x, int pos )
{
    Queue *now, *past;
    if (front == NULL)
        front = new Queue(x);
    else if (now != NULL && pos == 0)
    {
    now = front;
    ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            past = now;
            now = now->next;

        }
        past->next = new Queue(x, now);
    }
    else
    {
        now = front;
        int count = 0;
        while (now != NULL && count != pos)
        {
            past = now;
            now = now->next;
            count++;
        }
        past->next = new Queue(x, now);
    }
}
```

Here is my main

```
#include"queueType.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

queueType intqueue;

int input, temp, x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    intqueue.enqueue(i*i);
}
cout << "The values in the queue were:\n";
while (!intqueue.isEmpty())
{
    int value;
    intqueue.dequeue(value);
    cout << value << "  ";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    intqueue.enqueue(i*i);
}
cout << "\nEnter the value to find:" << endl;
cin >> input;
intqueue.search(input);
temp = intqueue.search(input);
intqueue.remove(temp);
intqueue.insert(input, 0);

cout << "\nThe values after change was made:\n";
while (!intqueue.isEmpty())
{
    int value;
    intqueue.dequeue(value);
    cout << value << "  ";
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I was trying to use insert function by position like this
void insert(int x, int pos); but it breaks if I put 0 for pos

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Time Check Failure

Comment: Maybe you should show the code you are talking about. It would be not help you for me to guess your implementation. I mean where is the code for `insert(int x, int pos)` So far you posted nothing that can help debug and you have not posted the error (or what you mean by it breaks).

Comment: I posted the whole code

Comment: ***Time Check Failure*** Is this the problem? c++ does not have the notion of an execution time limit. Does that mean you are running this on some online `c++` implementation with an execution time limit?

Comment: @ShafikOudeh _"I posted the whole code"_ Now narrow it down to a [MCVE] that reproduces the error please.

Comment: If you are running this online perhaps you will be better served with an IDE that you can run locally on your computer that has a debugger and no execution time limit at all.

Comment: No I'm not running it online. The problem is with the insert function. It makes the program break when I add it to the Main file.

Comment: Why do you assume / require that there are 5 items in your Queue if the front is not null?

Answer (score 1):

In insert method 
`else if (now != NULL && pos == 0)
    {`
this part can never run because now is null as it has never been initialized.
Then control goes to else part
where if pos =0 *past is never initialized.
Initialize *now first.
else you can remove else if part and just initialize *past once outside the while loop i.e.

```
else
{
    now = front;
    int count = 0;//here initialize past once past=now;
    while (now != NULL && count != pos)
    {
        past = now;
        now = now->next;
        count++;
    }
    past->next = new Queue(x, now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited it. It works for all positions except for 0 pos.
I need the element to go to the front of the queue.

```
   void queueType::insert(int x, int pos )
{
    Queue *now, *past;
   if (front == NULL)
    front = new Queue(x);
   else
  {
    now = front;

    int count = 0;
    while (now != NULL && count != pos)
    {
        past = now;
        now = now->next;
        count++;
    }
    past->next = new Queue(x, now);
}
```

}